# Why is my col-8 not in the middle of the grid system or aligned in the middle exactly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, centering, col

I've been learning from some videos how to use bootstrap4 and i was using the grid system but for some reason it is not aligned in the middle this is my code. is there anything i can change or maybe something related to that the video was still using the alpha version of bootstrap4.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body class="signin-body">
<div class="container signin-container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="card signin-card" style="width: 27rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="assets/DevslopesLogo.png" class="img-fluid signin-img" alt="Logo here">
            <form class="signin-form">
              <div class="form-group">          
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">               
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn signin-btn btn-lg">Sign In</button>
              <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
                  Remember me<a href="#"> Need Help?</a>
                </label>
              </div>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text .</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="create-new-account">Create New Account</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
  </div>  

</div>



  
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--  Always Download latest version of Boostrap and add here-->
  <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>```


so my col-8 is between two cols  and it was supposed to auto resize so why is it shifting to the left.


I was expecting it to be centre aligned automatically inside the row but it didn't work. it was to my knowledge that if I put col-8 in between two cols that they would automatically fit at least that's what appeared in the video.
````

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
col-8
```

To this line:

```
<div class="card signin-card" style="width: 27rem;">
```

Like this:

```
<div class="col-8 card signin-card" style="width: 27rem;">
```

And remove the following div:

```
<div class="col-8">
```

This should do the trick